# Is there a way to determine which OutputStream is currently sending through to my sockets inputstream?

Tags: java, sockets

This is my client right now:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        InputStream socketIn = socket.getInputStream();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(socketIn);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(socketIn);

        gui = new GuiController(out);

        while (true)
        {                   
            System.out.println(socketIn);
            if(in.hasNext()){
                gui.updateResponse(in.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

As you can see, I have both an ObjectInputStream as well as a Scanner. This is because I am both sending simple Strings from my Server, which should be caught by the string, as well as Hashtable-Objects, which are dealt by the ObjectInputStream.

However, now I need to determine whether my Servers PrintWriter or ObjectOutputStream sent the data, so I can react to it. If I don't make any check, my Scanner will just grab the object and print it as a string, which is obviously very wrong.

I need something like this:

```
if(socketIn.origin == ObjectOutputStream){

}
else{

}
```

Note that this is just some pseudo code, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: You need to use two separate sockets for this to work

Comment: You are sending serialized data over the network. Instead of sending a map have you considered using a library that does this sort of job for you. I am not aware of your application architecture or your use case but there are better alternatives that can be used to send the data from client to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is certainly not the recommended way of doing this for that look at EJP's answer.

But what you could do:
Before you send anything through your object stream or string stream, send a string through the string stream telling the client what to expect. After that you send the actual data via either the string stream or the object stream. So in pseudocode this would be:

```
read string with string input stream
if string==object then
    read data with object input stream
    handle object
else if string==string
    read data with string input stream
    handle string
```

This would work as you first receive what is coming, and then you read the actual data.

For the sake of completeness here's the pseudo code for the sender:

```
if the data to send==object
    print 'object' to the string output stream
    print object to the object ouput stream
else if data to send==string
    print 'string' to the string output stream
    print data string to the string ouput stream
```

I hope this helps you :)

NOTE: Be very carefull doing this when your socket is used by multiple threads.

NOTE: You could also wrap your string in an object and just send it through the object stream.

Comment: It won't work. The buffering in `ObjectInputStream` will steal data from the `Scanner,` and probably *vice versa* as well. It will also require extreme care in flushing after writing at the sending end.

Comment: That could be true, isn't there a way to turn the buffering off though? And from the question it seemed that this wasn't the case. But I'am not that familiar with how ObjectInputStream and Scanner handle their data.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is only one data stream. This will never work, for a number of reasons. Use a single stream, or reader/writer pair, or DataInput/OutputStream pair, or ObjectInput/OutputStream pair.